# TinyMCE.MVC.Jquery won't show?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

So working in visual studio 2012 I downloaded the TinyMCE.MVC.JQuery package and installed it using NuGet. Once in stalled i followed this tutorial to set it up:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget

My project is MVC3 and was already in exsistance so there are slight alterations.

This is my Controller create function:

```
 //
    // GET: /Pages/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Pages/Create

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(Database_Table database_table)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Database_Table.Add(database_table);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(database_table);
    }
```

My Edit:

```
  //
    // GET: /Pages/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Database_Table database_table = db.Database_Table.Find(id);
        return View(database_table);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Pages/Edit/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit(Database_Table database_table)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(database_table).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(database_table);
    }
```

This is my Model class:

```
public class Pages
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public string PageURL { get; set; }

    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string PageHTML { get; set; }


    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Database_Table> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Edit View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {


@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Pages</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageURL)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageURL)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageURL)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageHTML)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageHTML)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageHTML)
    </div>



    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
```

And both of these are referenced in the _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Sorry if I am being stupid but when I run the edit page the WYSIWYG editor doesnt display, its just a standard textbox. Can anyone see my problem?

Comment: Load the page in google chrome and right click on the page and select `Inspect Element`, check that there are no JS errors, they would be a red number on the bottom right of the page.

Comment: No Javascript Errors show up in google chrome or firebug :/

Comment: Interesting, everything looks good. Perhaps try to reinstall TinyMCE again. You may want to backup your project before hand.

Comment: Is the "~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js" reference already in the tinymce_jquery_full.cshtml custom editor? If so, you might be referencing it twice (once in layout, and once in the editor). You might not want that in the layout file - which you could be using for pages that have no TinyMCE fields.

Comment: I have this EXACT same problem. Regular text box shows. All the NUGET commands ran, I'm using MVC4 though.  You ever get an answer to this that worked?

Answer (score 0):

you're missing this in your view:

tinyMCE.init({

so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options

....
```

OR
If you're using Jquery plugin, you need this (in your view):

```
<!-- Load jQuery build -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
                $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : '../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
```

*remember: your textarea tag needs 'tinymce' class =>

```
<textarea id="content" name="content" class="tinymce" style="width:100%">
</textarea>
```

see examples on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jQuery referenced at the head part of the page. Or anywhere before your HTML editor.